# Testing with karma, jasmine, jquery and react using browserify

Tags: jquery, unit-testing, jasmine

I am currently starting a project that I would love to do using react js. But before I can start I need to figure out a good workflow including unit test, etc. The first problem that I have is that Jest has currently a bug that it makes it crash a soon as you require("jquery"). Since I couldn't find a way to debug Jest tests anyway I decided to try using karma with jasmine. The problem that I am now having is that when I try to test an ajax call I never get a response.

The current variation for the service is:

```
var _isTesting = false;
var deferred;
var TestService = {

 loginUser:function(username, password){

    var data = {
        username: username,
        password: password
    };
    console.log("calling ajax");

    return ($.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "https://test.com/service",
        data:data,
        dataType:"json"
    }));

  }
};
module.exports =TestService;
```

And the test looks like this:

```
describe('TestService', function(){
var onSuccess, onFailure, request;

var service = {};

beforeEach(function(){
    jasmine.Ajax.install();
    service = require("../js/services/TestService");
    onSuccess = jasmine.createSpy('onSuccess');
    onFailure = jasmine.createSpy('onFailure');
});

it('should set the testing variable', function(){
    expect(service.getIsTesting()).toBe(false);
    service.setIsTesting(true);
    expect(service.getIsTesting()).toBe(true);
});

it('should log in', function(){
    var def =  service.loginUser("username", "password");

    def.done(function(result){
            console.log("#######" + JSON.stringify(result))
            onSuccess(result);
        })
        .fail(function(error){
            console.log("#### ERROR ###"+JSON.stringify(error));
            onFailure(error);
        });

    request = jasmine.Ajax.requests.mostRecent();
    expect(request.url).toBe("https://test.com/service");
    expect(request.method).toBe('POST');

    expect(onSuccess).toHaveBeenCalled();
})
});
```

The firs to expects are successful but the third one fails, that is I never get a response from the ajax call.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the Jasmine docs (http://jasmine.github.io/2.2/ajax.html), you need to tell the framework to return data from the mocked AJAX call - it doesn't automatically respond with anything. Try something like:

```
....
expect(request.method).toBe('POST');

//respond to AJAX call
request.respondWith({
    "status": 200,
    "responseText": "some return data"
});

//now check that your success method was called
expect(onSuccess).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

As an aside on Jest - it doesn't currently support aliases, which is why your `require('jquery')` call won't work. (see this pull request: https://github.com/facebook/jest/pull/237). I haven't tried this, but you might get Jest working if you use a full path to require jquery instead of the alias. Something like `require('../node_modules/jquery');` It's annoying though, which is why I'm probably going to go with Karma/Jasmine as well for a new project.